# How to use correctly latexdiff with figures?

Tags: floats, latexdiff

I did change a source of some image between new and old version of `.tex` files, when I run `latexdiff` it marks such parts like this:

```
\DIFdelend %DIF > lamp
\DIFaddbegin \begin{figure*}[t]
\DIFaddendFL \begin{center} 

    \subfigure[] {\label{fig:result_lamp_img}\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth] {lamp_i\DIFdelbeginFL \DIFdelFL{mg1}\DIFdelendFL \DIFaddbeginFL \DIFaddFL{mg2}\DIFaddendFL .jpg}}
....
```

How to force `latexdiff` not to change the source of image files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things that may help:

1. it seems that the original source was `\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth] {something}`, with a space. If it is so, remove the space, it messes up latexdiff's parsing engine.
2. If this is not the cause of your error, I suggest that you double-check the value of the configuration variables `FLOATENV` and `PICTUREENV`, and change them in a config file to include `includegraphics` or `figure*` if needed. But there should already be some magic in place for `includegraphics` and `figure*`.

Comment: N1 was the problem, after i removed spaces everything compiled, thanks a lot!!!